# Netbeans 7.1.2 not able to detect the c++ compiler

Tags: gcc, netbeans, g++

I have completely installed cygwin. But yet netbeans not able to detect gcc/g++ compiler..

How do i avail gcc/g++ to netbeans..

Also i am finding gcc/g++ missing in c:\cygwin\bin..

Help me to get rid of these.. thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you select gcc / g++ package (Devel) while installing cygwin? If not install cygwin with selected gcc or better: install the whole cygwin package.

If Netbeans is unable to find your compiler, make shure you've set proper environment variables (PATH).